# MySQL ID PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT not staying in order

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble getting my database to stay organized I would like the ID field which is set to an `INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT` to stay in numerical order. The problem comes when I delete all of the entries in the database. Before deleting the entries everything is in order as intended, after deleting instead of going in numerical order starting with the smaller integer first it will always go in descending order. Can someone explain what is causing this.

```
+----+------------+----------+---------+----------------+-----------+------------+-----------+---------+
| id | employeeID | date     | timeIn  | jobDescription | equipType | unitNumber | unitHours | timeOut |
+----+------------+----------+---------+----------------+-----------+------------+-----------+---------+
|  1 |          2 | 01/13/13 | 1:19 pm | Test1          | Dozer     | 1D         |        98 | 1:20 pm |
|  2 |          2 | 01/13/13 | 1:20 pm | Test2          | Dozer     | 1D         |        98 | 1:20 pm |
+----+------------+----------+---------+----------------+-----------+------------+-----------+---------+
```

AFTER DELETING ALL ROWS:

```
+----+------------+----------+---------+----------------+-----------+------------+-----------+---------+
| id | employeeID | date     | timeIn  | jobDescription | equipType | unitNumber | unitHours | timeOut |
+----+------------+----------+---------+----------------+-----------+------------+-----------+---------+
|  4 |          2 | 01/13/13 | 1:22 pm | Test2          | Dozer     | 1D         |        98 | 1:22 pm |
|  3 |          2 | 01/13/13 | 1:22 pm | Test1          | Dozer     | 1D         |        98 | 1:22 pm |
+----+------------+----------+---------+----------------+-----------+------------+-----------+---------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that without an `ORDER BY` clause in your `SELECT` query, the order is effectively not deterministic and you cannot and should not rely on it being in any particular order.

What I see here is `Test2` inserted with `id=4`, and assuming you first inserted the `Test1` row, then your `auto_increment` is working as expected.

If you simply did something like `SELECT * FROM thistable`, do not expect the rows to be ordered by `id ASC`. Add an `ORDER BY` clause to be explicit about it.

```
SELECT * FROM thistable ORDER BY id ASC
```

Since all the other columns between these two new rows have equal values, whichever column MySQL has chosen to sort on absent an explicit `ORDER BY` doesn't have anything to differentiate.